# Why is parameter to string.indexOf method is an int in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, primitive-types

I am wondering why the parameter to indexOf method an int , when the description says a char.

public int indexOf(int ch)

```
Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified **character**
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29

```
Also, both of these compiles fine:
char c = 'p';
str.indexOf(2147483647);
str.indexOf(c);
```

a]Basically, what I am confused about is int in java is 32bit , while unicode characters are 16 bits .

b]Why not use the character themselves rather than using int . Is this any performance optimization ?. Are chars difficult to represent than int ? How ?

I assume this should be simple reasoning for this and that makes me know about it even more !

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The **real** reason is that `indexOf(int)` expects a Unicode codepoint, not a 16-bit UTF-16 "character".  Unicode code points are actually up to 21 bits in length.

(The UTF-16 representation of a longer codepoint is actually 2 16-bit "character" values.  These values are known as leading and trailing surrogates; D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>, and DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub> respectively; see [Unicode FAQ - UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) for the gory details.)

If you give `indexOf(int)` a code point > 65535 it will search for the *pair* of UTF-16 characters that encode the codepoint.

This is stated by the javadoc (albeit not very clearly), and an examination of the code indicates that this is indeed how the method is implemented.

---

> Why not just use 16-bit characters ?

That's pretty obvious.  If they did that, there wouldn't be an easy way to locate code points greater than 65535 in Strings.  That would be a major problem for people who develop internationalized applications where text may contain such code points.  (A lot of supposedly internationalized applications make the incorrect assumption that a `char` represents a code point.  Often it doesn't matter, but increasingly often it does.)

But it shouldn't make any difference to you.  The method will still work if your Strings consist of only 16 bit codes ... or, for that matter, of only ASCII codes.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. okay, so now I see indexOf(int) expects a Unicode codepoint, my other question was .. why is that ? . Why not just use 16-bit characters ?

Comment: Because a unicode charecter is really 22 bits, and not 16. So there are 'chars/letters' (code points) which can't be stored in a java char. Which is why a Java string may use 2 chars to store one 'codepoint/letter' (See utf-16 surrogate pairs, if you really want to know).

Answer (score 4):

Characters in Java are stored in their unicode integer representation. The [Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class documentation has more details about this format.

From the docs on that page:

> The methods that accept an int value support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters. For example, Character.isLetter(0x2F81A) returns true because the code point value represents a letter (a CJK ideograph).

Comment: Thnx. 2 statements from the doc:

The lower (least significant) 21 bits of int are used to represent Unicode code points and the upper (most significant) 11 bits must be zero.

Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities

So if unicode are 16 bits, why use 21 bits to represent them ?

Comment: Yes, but Strings are byte[] under the covers, encoded as UTF-8. Standard characters (0-255) occupy only one byte (not two bytes that a full width char would occupy). Characters over 255 take multiple bytes, sometimes more than 2 bytes. An encoded character has an integer (32-bit) equivalent - that is what indexOf() searches for

Comment: @p1 Unicode hasn't been 16-bit for a very long time. Unicode 2.0 removed the 16-bit restriction, and that was FIFTEEN years ago (I feel old). Technically ISO-10646 is a 31-bit address space, and Unicode could in theory represent any of that. In reality, UTF-16 is restricted to 21 bits, and Unicode has effectively committed to only supporting those 21 bits. It's extremely unlikely that ISO-10646 will ever be allowed to go out of sync with Unicode in a way that would break UTF-16, so 21-bit is effectively now a hardcoded limit.

Comment: @Bohemian - Your comment about String being `byte[]` under the covers is not correct.  The normal in-memory representation uses a `char[]` ... not UTF-8.

Comment: @StephenC I was dumber back then :/ - Shot you an upvote for trawling back to find this in a *comment* though (you must be psychic or obsessive :) )

Comment: @Bohemian - I saw some "activity" on my Answer ... and noticed your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The method `str.indexOf(int)` takes an int. If you pass a `char` into it, java will cast the `char` to `int`, since `char` is a 16-bit number.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a whole slew of implicit typecasting rules being carried out under the hood. For primitives, there are special rules, which are all outlined in the document [Conversions and Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html), part of Sun's Java documentation. For your specific question, the conversion of int to char is a "narrowing primitive conversion." See section 5.1.3 in the above document.

That being said, it's a common programming practice to interchange small positive integers and characters which are encoded as integers. This goes back to their use indistinguishable use in C, when ASCII was all that existed.