# Indexof () argument type

Tags: java, types, arguments, indexof

Example1: indexOf(int ch)  //ex:   s.indexOf('y');
Example2:replace(char original, char replacement)

In both the examples the argument is expecting type char. Though it's mentioned as int in example 1 ,at the end it is expecting argument with single quote which is character. It could have directly been like char ch. Why there exists int type?  They could have specified it same like example 2.

Is there any internal reason for this.why the syntax differs in some cases. There must a reason to do so.  Plz explain me this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is parameter to string.indexOf method is an int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210231/why-is-parameter-to-string-indexof-method-is-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand difference between `char` data type, and *code point* of a symbol.

`char` is just an unsigned 16-bit value. But *code point* is a number which represents one unicode character. Code points are encoded using [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding, they can be represented by one or two (so-called *surrogate pair*) 16-bit values. Strings in java uses that encoding, thus each character can be represented by one or two `char` values.

In vast majority of cases, code points uses only one `char` which value equals to the code point, so, many programmers just ignore the difference. But `indexOf` method understands it's and if a number higher than 0xFFFF is provided and it is a valid code point, then the method will look for sequence of two surrogate values.

Note, the result of the method, as all offsets in Strings, and `.length()` are in `chars` not in actual code points. But, as mentioned above, in most cases you can just ignore the difference.

See [`indexOf` documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))